# How to mergen content of multiple sql columns in a new row?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I want to read two sql cols and combine them, separated by a space. The result should be written into a new column.

How can I get the space in?

```
insert into mytable (theRow)
select one, two from mytable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT concat(one,' ', two) from mytable